# Using CoreLocation2d

Tags: swift, cllocationcoordinate2d

Im trying to get the distance from my current location to some location but it not printing the location. Im not sure if I use it the extension right.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.distanceInMetersFrom(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10.30, longitude: 44.34))

        print("distance = \(location)")
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {

    func distanceInMetersFrom(otherCoord : CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let firstLoc = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
        let secondLoc = CLLocation(latitude: otherCoord.latitude, longitude: otherCoord.longitude)
        return firstLoc.distanceFromLocation(secondLoc)
    }

}
```

The output is like this:

```
distance = (Function)
```

Comment: You have requested permissions to iOS for accessing location already?

Comment: yes I added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in info.list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your extension is suited for an instance of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

> For it to work you need to call it in an instance, so:
>
> change:

```
var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.distanceInMetersFrom(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10.30, longitude: 44.34))
```

> for

```
var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D().distanceInMetersFrom(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10.30, longitude: 44.34))
```

> Notice the parenthesis after `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

**If you want to keep this line exactly like it is, then the changes in your extension will be like this:**

```
static func distanceInMetersFrom(otherCoord : CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
            let here = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
            let firstLoc = CLLocation(latitude: here.latitude, longitude: here.longitude)
            let secondLoc = CLLocation(latitude: otherCoord.latitude, longitude: otherCoord.longitude)
            return firstLoc.distanceFromLocation(secondLoc)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to compute the distance from your current location to (10.30, 44.34).
This is done by using:

```
let baseLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 10.30, longitude: 44.34)
let distance = locationManager.location?.distanceFromLocation(baseLocation)
```

`locationManager.location` is the last location detected by the CLLocationManager. If your app didn't `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` and call CLLocationManager `requestLocation()`, `startUpdatingLocation()` or `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` and obtained a location fix, this property (and the computed distance) would be `nil`.